# Is there way to drop duplicate rows based on the order(combinations) within same id?

Tags: pandas

Is there a way to remove rows with duplicated order within same traceId and average the 'duration' column?

For example,

```
start_df = pd.DataFrame({'traceId':['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b', 'c','c','c','c'],
                          'service':['cartservice', 'frontend-proxy', 'frontend-proxy', 'frontend',
                                     'cartservice', 'frontend-proxy', 'frontend-proxy', 'frontend', 'a','a','b','c'],
                          'operation': ['router frontend egress', 'ingress', 'oteldemo.CartService/GetCart', 'GET',
                                        'router frontend egress', 'ingress', 'oteldemo.CartService/GetCart', 'GET', 'a-1', 'a-1', 'b-1', 'c-1'],
                          'duration': [1,2,3,4, 2,3,4,5, 5,5,5,5]})
```

start_df looks like this:

[start_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNLWX.png)

result_df should be this:

```
result_df =  pd.DataFrame({'traceId':['a','a','a','a', 'c','c','c','c'],
                          'service':['cartservice', 'frontend-proxy', 'frontend-proxy', 'frontend', 'a','a','b','c'],
                          'operation': ['router frontend egress', 'ingress', 'oteldemo.CartService/GetCart', 'GET', 'a-1','a-1','b-1','c-1'],
                          'duration': [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5,5,5,5,5]})
```

[result_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrqRP.png)

as you can see, the duplicated rows (because they have same order of service+operation combination within same traceId) are removed and their durations of each service+operation were averaged out.

How can I achieve this with pandas code?

I tried

```
# Your DataFrame
merged_df = pd.DataFrame({'traceId':['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b', 'c','c','c','c'],
                          'service':['cartservice', 'frontend-proxy', 'frontend-proxy', 'frontend',
                                     'cartservice', 'frontend-proxy', 'frontend-proxy', 'frontend', 'a','a','b','c'],
                          'operation': ['router frontend egress', 'ingress', 'oteldemo.CartService/GetCart', 'GET',
                                        'router frontend egress', 'ingress', 'oteldemo.CartService/GetCart', 'GET', 'a-1', 'a-1', 'b-1', 'c-1'],
                          'duration': [1,2,3,4, 2,3,4,5, 5,5,5,5]})

# Define a function to check if the 'service' and 'operation' order is the same
def has_same_order(group):
    return group['service'].eq(group['service'].iloc[0]).all() and group['operation'].eq(group['operation'].iloc[0]).all()

# Group by 'traceId' and filter groups with the same 'service' and 'operation' order
result_df = merged_df.groupby('traceId').filter(has_same_order)

# Calculate the average duration for each group
result_df = result_df.groupby(['traceId', 'service', 'operation'], as_index=False)['duration'].mean()

print(result_df)
```

but it didn't turn out right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code**

```
tmp = start_df.groupby('traceId')[['service', 'operation']].agg(tuple)
m = tmp.groupby(['service', 'operation']).ngroup()
grp = start_df.groupby(['traceId', 'service', 'operation']).cumcount()
out = (start_df.groupby([start_df['traceId'].map(m), grp, 'service', 'operation'], sort=False)
               .agg({'traceId': 'first', 'duration':'mean'})
               .droplevel([0, 1]).reset_index().reindex(start_df.columns, axis=1))
```

out:

```
  traceId         service                     operation  duration
0       a     cartservice        router frontend egress       1.5
1       a  frontend-proxy                       ingress       2.5
2       a  frontend-proxy  oteldemo.CartService/GetCart       3.5
3       a        frontend                           GET       4.5
4       c               a                           a-1       5.0
5       c               a                           a-1       5.0
6       c               b                           b-1       5.0
7       c               c                           c-1       5.0
```